# How to use equations from Online Latex Equation Editor to word 2007

Tags: html, ms-word, latex, mathml

I had seen some of the ways of using the equations from online latex equation editor in word but they are not working for me.

1. using of [chorme extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/latex2word-equation/oicdodhdflfciojjhbhnhpeenbpfipfg) , but in word 2007 it is not working only I can paste code of equation.
2. after writing equations, download the image of type gif, svg, png etc and use them in word.

But I think there is another way of using some MathML code or HTML code form online latex equation editor to word. Can someone help me

Comment: What's wrong with option (2)? Is that not working for you?

Comment: @Werner  second option is working but there is another way of using MathML code directly which I had used long back. I am trying to figure it out.